# Overloaded method error when accessing audio file length with taglib-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to get the length of audio files and save them to the :duration column in the database. I'm using the tablib-ruby gem. The :audio symbol refers to the audio url.
Here is the code in my model that is erroneous:

```
         require 'taglib'

         class Track < ApplicationRecord
         before_save :set_duration

         def set_duration
            # :duration is an integer
            # t.integer  "duration",                  :default => 0
            TagLib::FileRef.open(:audio) do |file|
              update_column(:duration, file.audio_properties.length) unless file.null?
            end
          end
```

Doing this results in the following error when I try to save an audio file.

```
Wrong arguments for overloaded method 'FileRef.new'. Possible C/C++ prototypes are: FileRef.new() FileRef.new(TagLib::FileName fileName, bool readAudioProperties, TagLib::AudioProperties::ReadStyle audioPropertiesStyle) FileRef.new(TagLib::FileName fileName, bool readAudioProperties) FileRef.new(TagLib::FileName fileName) FileRef.new(TagLib::File *file) FileRef.new(TagLib::FileRef const &ref)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are passing a symbol to the `open` method `open(:audio)`, where you actually want to pass the audio `open(audio)`.

Comment: Yes, this is where I was going wrong. The problem I'm having now is that I'm trying to do this process before save while using the tempfile of the uploaded audio track. I cannot seem to access the audio file from the tempfile or from Amazon S3.